# Unity3d access int field with button.onClick.AddListner(Delegate...)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, onclicklistener

I'm using a prefab of a button and creating a number of buttons at runtime. While adding listners from script(C#) I can't add value from a list using index (The int field in the title).

```
for (int i=0; i<messageList.Count; i++) {
        Button msgBtnObj = Instantiate (msgListPrefabObj) as Button;
        MessageListPrefabScript msgListPrefabScriptRef = msgBtnObj.GetComponent<MessageListPrefabScript> ();
        msgListPrefabScriptRef.msgText.text = msglistToShow[i].msgFieldText;  //here i works
        msgBtnObj.transform.SetParent (msglistPanel);
        msgBtnObj.name = "msgbtn_" + msglistToShow [i].msgFieldText;  //here i works
        msgBtnObj.GetComponent<Button> ().onClick.AddListener(delegate { clickedOnMsg(messageList [i]); });  //here i doesn't work

    }
```

The last line gives me a ArgumentOutOfRangeException. Now if I use 1,2,3 etc. it works. But how can I use a variable, e.g. the loop iterator i ?

This is the stacktrace of the exception,

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.
Parameter name: index
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String].get_Item (Int32 index) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs:633)
CreateMsgListScript+<PopulateMsglist>c__AnonStorey9.<>m__1 () (at   Assets/CreateMsgListScript.cs:74)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke (System.Object[] args) (at /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:137)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:601)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:743)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent_0.cs:53)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () (at /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:35)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick  (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:44)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:52)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[IPointerClickHandler] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1 functor) (at /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:269)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()
```

Comment: Are you changing the messageList content later on? Like removing items from it?

Comment: Agree with @fafase, 90% this is the cause

Comment: I had this problem too, check my answer.

Comment: @JerrySwitalski where is your answer?

Comment: No @DenisEfimov my messageList is not changing. In fact I have also tried with a static list (with hard coded values to test if the problem was the list).

Comment: Add logging into your clickedOnMsg() function to check what values it has

Comment: @DenisEfimov My list is having it's expected value. But how can i execute clickedOnMsg(string) if the iterator i is having the exception? If I print my list anywhere, it shows expected values.

Comment: Sorry, i mean add logging before clickedOnMsg() like this: delegate { Debug.Log(messageList.Length); clickedOnMsg(messageList [i]); }

Comment: @DenisEfimov Debug log prints right values. Both Debug.Log(messageList.Length) AND Debug.Log(i) prints expected values.

Comment: Ok, please show me the code of clickedOnMsg and share stacktrace to see who throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException. Is it the problem to see your error there?

Comment: Can you please post the declaration of "messageList"?

Comment: @DenisEfimov please check the edited post for the stacktrace

Comment: I don't understand why this question is being downvoted. I have searched quite a bit on the internet for any solution. Those people who think this should be downvoted, at least could provide the solution.

Comment: Your question is downvoted becouse of too liitle info you provided. CreateMsgListScript  - in your assests, what happens on 74 line? Why didn't you examined your stacktrace before to ask question? Your problem is that someone calls collection with index of more then its size. Also you didn't mentioned place where you adding your listener. Try to add listener without anonimous function

Comment: @DenisEfimov 74th line is exactly the one I have mentioned and pointed more than once, where the exception occurs. 
"...<Button> ().onClick.AddListener(delegate { clickedOnMsg(messageList [i]); })"
I had examined the stacktrace before posting the question here. if I could solve then there was no point of asking. Now, as i have already told that index value is perfect because I have used Debug.Log to check that. Should I think I can't add listeners dynamically from script through functions, because you're saying so?Moreover the listener is getting added, as I've already mentioned more than once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UnityAction delegate you use must have zero params - http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.AddListener.html and http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityAction.html And you are trying to pass collection element.

Comment: You can use params in onClick Delegate. See this answer http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/797772/example-of-setting-up-a-button-onclick-event-via-s.html

Comment: see comment on page your provided: "Though it's worth noting that some variables won't pass properly,". This is what we have in original question

Answer (score 1):

Since we still need more information to help you solve the problem, I am still going to give you an answer that might help.
You are iterating through "messageList" List but you are using its index to access "msglistToShow". This why I think you are getting "ArgumentOutOfRangeException".

"messageList" and "msglistToShow" may have different size/count.

Comment: They both have same size. Though I will like to inform you that after reading your solution, I tried using the messagelist index. The error was same. But however if I put,   msgBtnObj.GetComponent<Button> ().onClick.AddListener(delegate {  i=5; clickedOnMsg(messageList [i]); });     it works. Somehow, the value of i is getting null or so inside the delegate.